# Using BIM 360 Field API to download a checklist as a PDF file

Tags: autodesk-bim360

I need to download a checklist as a PDF file by using the APIs of BIM 360 Field. Is this possible? I'm trying to use the command POST /api/binary_data without any success. Do I need, instead, to create the PDF myself after using the GET /fieldapi/checklists/v1/:id ?

Comment: Hi Shamri, for BIM 360 Field API questions please refer to the following support blog - https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/bim-360-api-forum/bd-p/115

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you need to make the GET request to /fieldapi/checklists/v1/:id, then create the pdf yourself.

Also note that to retrieve custom fields from a checklist, you need to change at least one of the fields from the default values.

Or if you have the time you can play with [Microsoft Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/), to download the report on a schedule.